# Using PHP and CURL to log in to a website

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to fetch a page `https://example.com/my-receipts` after posting a login to `https://example.com/sessions`.  I'm being correctly logged in, but I'm not being taken to the `/my-receipts` page (I can see I'm logged in from the resulting page, but it's catching some exception and redirecting me to a help page).

This is the code I'm using:

```
//initial request with login data

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/sessions');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://example.com/dashboard");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'email='.urlencode($email).'&password='.urlencode($password).'&_token=');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '4.cookie');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '4.cookie');
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo "[E1] ".curl_error($ch);
}

//another request preserving the session

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/my-receipts');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo "[E2] ".curl_error($ch);
}

echo $answer;
```

The website I'm trying to fetch the page from is running Laravel with Angular JS on nginx. I've been able to fetch other pages after logging in with this code.  Is is possible there's something specific to the framework that's preventing me?

Comment: I'd recommend using the site normally and watching the browser console during a normal load of `/my-receipts`. Look for additional fields posted back, like a CSRF token for example.

Comment: if you can show us the real website, and give us a test account, we could probably be of more help. but yeah, do what @MichaelBerkowski suggested, log in with the browser, log the login procedure with developer tools, and replicate it with curl, that's what i always do, and chrome's developer tools "Network Tab" is invaluable for that